# A mistake in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
var text = "Price: 123 dollar."
text.replace(/((\d+\.?\d+?)|(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})+)) *([a-zA-Z]+)/, function(a,b,c){
document.write(a+" | "+b+" | "+c);
return;
}
```

Now The output is: **123 dollar | 123 | 123**

But I need the output to be: **123 dollar | 123 | dollar**

It works with the regex /\b((?:\d+.)?\d+) *([a-zA-Z]+)/

Can't figure it out.. Why b and c are the same?!

**Fix:** The solution was to remove unnecessary capture groups:

/((**?:**\d+.?\d+?)|(**?:**\d{1,3}(**?:**\,\d{3})+)) *([a-zA-Z]+)/

Thanks @Mythril and  @cababunga

Comment: `/(\d+\.?\d+?|\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+) *([a-zA-Z]+)/`

Comment: You can just remove the grouping like what I suggested in the comment above - no point in grouping there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you created more capture groups. Which means more parameters to the replace function, try this:

```
var text = "Price: 123 dollar."
text.replace(/((\d+\.?\d+?)|(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})+)) *([a-zA-Z]+)/, function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
    document.write(a+" | "+b+" | "+f);}
);
```

Comment: Understood.. Any idea how to remove unnecessary captured groups?

Comment: If you only need groupping, use (?:)  `(?:(\d+\.?\d+?)|(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})+))`